# Enterrise Architect MDG Technology in DFD

Tags: modeling, enterprise-architect, dfd

Thank you in advance for your helping

I am using Sparx Enterprise Architect one year ago, and I have a good experience in it.

Actually, I started to create my own toolbox using MDG Technology, this toolbox contains some different diagrams. I already created what I need in this toolbox and it works correctly. However, I have a problem with the Data Flow Diagram (DFD) symbols, I wasted a lot of time to find the name of the DFD stereotypes.

I need a help, how I can create DFD on the Profile page in MDG like the following: 
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your screenshot does not really help in guessing what you are trying to achieve. So can you please be more specific.

Comment: What's wrong with using EA's DFD MDG?

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your answering

I cannot find the names of DFD stereotypes in MDG technology to create my own toolbox

How I can find the names of stereotypes to use for creating Profile, Toolbox, and the Diagram

Hope that is clear to you now

Comment: the toolbox for dfd is named Data Flow Diagrams in EA, it's also the name of the technology

Comment: Please specify which stereotypes you want to recreate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stereotypes for DFD are(UML Base Types in parentheses):

- DFD_Process (Class)
- DFD_External (Class)
- DFD_DataStore (Class)
- DFD_DataFlow (Connector:Dependency)
- Gate doesn't have a stereotype, the uml base subtype is MessageEndPoint
- There is no stereotype for a DFD Diagram, so you can use a process diagram.

This information was taken from EA's own DataFlow toolbox.

The toolbox is named Data Flow Diagrams, and to get it you need the Data Flow Diagrams MDG.

To get the stereotype/base class information, drag each element on a diagram and select them, the stereotype will show in the property window.

For the base class, you need to select the element and have the property window (alt+1), then click the button with three dots (see screenshot), it will show you the base class

[image: click the button with three dots in the type field]

Comment: thank you, Mr. @Hue for your answer

I already did what you said, but I still have a problem.

I define the type as a 'Class', and the Metatype as 'DFD_External'.

the next step, I create the toolbox with the created element.
finally, I generated the toolbox, but when I drag and drop the 'External' element, nothing happened.
do you have suggestions !!!

greetings,

Comment: So many things can go wrong when making mdg profiles so im nut sure i cant help you if you aren't creating your mdg correctly, at least, make sure your profile is correct by saving the profile and then importing it, then the stereotypes will appear in the resources Window (deactive your mdg while doing this)

Comment: Okay, I will it and follow ur steps to solve this problem